# How to send Query Parameter to Logic App from API Management

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am receiving a GET request in API management (https://devapi.testcustomer.com.au//bankv2?bsbNumber=123-456) and transforming it to POST call to Logic App. How can I pass the `bsbNumber` query parameter from the incoming request to Logic App?

I am setting the logic app Url inside API Policy:

```
<set-backend-service base-url="https://prod-05.*******.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/******b187aef1f5/triggers/request/run" />
<set-method>POST</set-method>
<rewrite-uri template="?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=%2Ftriggers%2Frequest%2Frun&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig=*****tdiDL8" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the expression `context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("bsbNumber`") 
to get the value of bsbNumber from querystring. You can use it to create a parameter in the redirect URI.

List of all possible expressions in Azure API managment.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn910913.aspx